# Finding the average maximum pairing of two vector

Tags: r, vector, max

I have an integer variable `res` which stores the sum of of each element from one vector to another vector where the results are kept track.

```
a <- 1:3
b <- 4:6
nm <- outer(seq_along(a), seq_along(b), FUN = function(x, y) sprintf('a%d + b%d', x, y))
res <- setNames(c(outer(a,b,`+`)), nm)

res 
#   a1 + b1 a2 + b1 a3 + b1 a1 + b2 a2 + b2 a3 + b2 a1 + b3 a2 + b3 a3 + b3 
#      5       6       7       6       7       8       7       8       9
```

How can I find the maximum of each unique pair? Let say `a3 + b3 = 9` is the maximum, then in the second iteration, any pair containing `a3` or `b3` are omitted and we are left with:

```
res 
#   a1 + b1 a2 + b1 a1 + b2 a2 + b2 
#      5       6         6       7
```

The next maximum is `a2 + b2 = 7`, then in the last iteration, any pair with `a2` or `b2` are omitted and we are left with:

```
res 
#   a1 + b1  
#      5
```

Then we can average the maximum pairing i.e. `(9+7+5)/3 = 3`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: YOu may need a `for` loop to omit this by `grep`ing the names that have the max value i.e. `res[!grepl(sub(" \\+ ", "|", names(which.max(res))), names(res))]`

Comment: Shouldn't `mean` of `(9+7+5)/3 = 7`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a function with `repeat` to assign the output dervied from removing the elements have the maximum value (by `grep`ing the names of the named vector to subset the original vector) until it reaches a `length` of 1

```
f1 <- function(x) {
  x1 <- max(x)
 repeat {
  x <- x[!grepl(sub(" \\+ ", "|", names(which.max(x))), names(x))]
  x1 <- c(x1, max(x))
  if(length(x)==1) break
   }
  return(list(x, mean(x1)))

 }

f1(res)
#[[1]]
# a1 + b1 
#   5 

#[[2]]
#[1] 7
```

Comment: how can I modify the `if` statement in `f1()` when the length of variables `a` and `b` changes? i.e. `length(a) = 10` and `length(b) = 15 or 20 or 25`., such that length of `a` is fixed, but length `b` can be any number of a multiple of 5?

Comment: @jacky_learns_to_code  Could you post that as a new question as it is not clear about your expected

Comment: I have posted a new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43737524/finding-the-average-mean-pairing-of-two-vector