# Finding the average mean pairing of two vector

Tags: r, vector, sum

I have an integer variable `res` which stores the sum of of each element from one vector to another vector where the results are kept track. Where `length(a) = 10` and `length(b) = 10 or 15 or any length > length(a).`

```
a <- 1:10
b <- 1:15
nm <- outer(seq_along(a), seq_along(b), FUN = function(x, y) sprintf('a%d + b%d', x, y))
res <- setNames(c(outer(a,b,`+`)), nm)

res 
#    a1+b1   a2+b1   a3+b1   a4+b1   a5+b1 ... a6+b15  a7+b15  a8+b15  a9+b15 a10+b15
#    2       3       4       5       6     ... 21      22      23      24      25
```

How can I find the maximum of each unique pair? Let say `a10 + b15 = 25` is the maximum, then in the second iteration, any pair containing `a10` or `b15` are omitted. This process is repeated until no unique pairs are left.

How can I modify the `if` statement in the below function to find the mean of the maximum unique pairing? Or there is another way round?

```
f1 <- function(x) {
  x1 <- max(x)
 repeat {
  x <- x[!grepl(sub(" \\+ ", "|", names(which.max(x))), names(x))]
  x1 <- c(x1, max(x))
  if(length(x)==1) break
   }
  return(list(x, mean(x1)))

 }
```

*Note: This question is a follow-up of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43731301/finding-the-average-maximum-pairing-of-two-vector).*

Comment: your condition is not clear to me.  Are you saying that if the max value is in `a7 + b9` those elements that contain either a7 or b9 in their names will not be omitted?  Or is like `a5 + b10`, `a10 + b15`, `a10 + b5`,  `a5 + b15`, `a5 + b5`, `a10 + b10`  and is there any other combinations?

Comment: The other way round, if the max value is in `a7 + b9`, then those elements that contain either `a7` or `b9` in their names will be omitted. Then in the next iteration, if the max value is in `a3 + b3`, then `a3` or `b3` will be remove, and so on...

Comment: I am confused with multiples of 5 part.  What is your expected output?

Comment: Changing `a` to `a <- 1:10` and `b` to `b <- 1:15` using your previous solution, I have came across this warning `no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf`. Maybe this error explains what I am trying to solve i.e when the length of `a` and `b` are not equal. Sorry to confuse you with the multiples of 5 part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can change the function to

```
f2 <- function(x) {
   x1 <- max(x)
   repeat {
   i1 <- grepl(sub(" \\+ ", "|", names(which.max(x))), names(x))
 if(all(i1)) break
  x  <-  x[!i1]
  x1 <- c(x1, max(x))

}

return(list(x, mean(x1)))
}

f2(res)
#[[1]]
#a1 + b1 a1 + b2 a1 + b3 a1 + b4 a1 + b5 a1 + b6 
#      2       3       4       5       6       7 

#[[2]]
#[1] 16
```

Comment: Thank you so much akrun, my apologies for replying slow, I was manually calculating the expected output. Yes, the answer is 16. You are way way ahead!